# F# Immutable data structures for high frequency real-time streaming data

Tags: data-structures, f#, stream, f#-3.0, f#-data

We are at the beginning of an f# project involving real-time and historical analysis of streaming data. The data is contained in a c# object (see below) and is sent as part of a standard .net event. In real-time, the number of events we typically receive can vary greatly from less than 1/sec to upwards of around 800 events per second per instrument and thus can be very bursty. A typical day might accumulate 5 million rows/elements per insturment

A generic version of the C# event's data structure looks like this:

```
public enum MyType { type0 = 0, type1 = 1}

public class dataObj
{
    public int myInt= 0;
    public double myDouble;
    public string myString;
    public DateTime myDataTime;
    public MyType type;
    public object myObj = null;

}
```

We plan to use this data structure in f# in two ways:

1. Historical analysis using supervised && unsupervised  machine learning (CRFs, clustering models, etc)
2. Real-time classification of data streams using the above models

The data structure needs to be able to grow as we add more events. This rules out `array<t>` because it does not allow for resizing, though it could be used for the historical analysis. The data structure also needs to be able to quickly access recent data and ideally needs to be able to jump to data x points back. This rules out `Lists<T>` because of the linear lookup time and because there is no random access to elements, just "forward-only" traversal.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407772/f-immutable-variable-sized-window-data-structure), `Set<T>` may be a good choice...

[> " ...Vanilla Set<'a> does a more than adequate job. I'd prefer a 'Set' over a 'List' so you always have O(lg n) access to the largest and smallest items, allowing you to ordered your set by insert date/time for efficient access to the newest and oldest items..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407772/f-immutable-variable-sized-window-data-structure)

EDIT: Yin Zhu response gave me some additional clarity into exactly what I was asking. I have edited the remainder of the post to reflect this. Also, the previous version of this question was muddied by the introduction of requirements for historical analysis. I have omitted them.

Here is a breakdown of the steps of the real-time process:

1. A realtime event is received
2. This event is placed in a data structure. **This is the data structure that we are trying to determine**. Should it be a `Set<T>`, or some other structure?
3. A subset of the elements are either extracted or somehow iterated over for the purpose of feature generation. This would either be the last n rows/elements of the data structure (ie. last 1000 events or 10,000 events) or all the elements in the last x secs/mins (i.e all the events in the last 10 min). Ideally, we want a structure that allows us to do this efficiently. In particular, a data structure that allows for random access of the nth element without iteration through all the others elements is of value.
4. Features for the model are generated and sent to a model for evaluation.
5. We may prune the data structure of older data to improve performance.

So the question is what is the best data structure to use for storing the real-time streaming events that we will use to generated features.

Comment: Just found this post on using mailbox processor to act as a thread-safe message handling queue for high frequency sensor data. Somewhat relevant http://stackoverflow.com/a/928892/628094

Comment: A skip list is worth considering for the O(log n) random access, searching for times, cumulative statistics, etc. Someone has an F# implementation here: http://ffogd.blogspot.co.uk/2010/10/f-skip-list.html

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but if you are at the beginning of a project you may want to look at Rx. The environment you describe has streams of data coming in asynchronously. Rx lets you compose these streams and operate on them directly, also with Linq, sliding windows etc. So you could do pretty sophisticated real-time analysis on the 'live' stream even before committing it to some data structure. [here](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/01_WhyRx.html) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should consider  [FSharpx.Collections.Vector](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Collections/blob/master/src/FSharpx.Collections/PersistentVector.fsi). Vector<T> will give you Array-like features, including indexed O(log32(n)) look-up and update, which is within spitting distance of O(1), as well as adding new elements to the end of your sequence. There is another implementation of Vector which can be used from F# at [Solid Vector](https://github.com/GregRos/Solid). Very well documented and some functions perform up to 4X faster at large scale (element count > 10K). Both implementations perform very well up to and possibly beyond 1M elements.

Comment: Thanks Jack! This seems to be precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: As Rich Hickey said, "You would be very much surprised by how good the performance is."

Answer (score 10):

In his answer, Jack Fox suggests using either the FSharpx.Collections `Vector<'T>` or the Solid `Vector<'t>` by Greg Rosenbaum (https://github.com/GregRos/Solid). I thought I might give back a bit to the community by providing instructions on how to get up and running with each of them.

### Using the FSharpx.Collections.Vector<'T>

The process is pretty straight forward:

1. Download the FSharpx.Core nuget package using either the Project Manager Console or Manager Nuget Packages for Solution. Both are found in Visual Studio -> tools -> Library Manager.
2. If you're using it in F# script file add `#r "FSharpx.Core.dll"`. You may need to use a full path.

Usage:

```
open FSharpx.Collections

let ListOfTuples = [(1,true,3.0);(2,false,1.5)] 
let vector = ListOfTuples |> Vector.ofSeq

printfn "Last %A" vector.Last
printfn "Unconj %A" vector.Unconj
printfn "Item(0) %A" (vector.[0])
printfn "Item(1) %A" (vector.[1])
printfn "TryInitial %A" dataAsVector.TryInitial
printfn "TryUnconj %A" dataAsVector.Last
```

---

### Using the Solid.Vector<'T>

Getting setup to use the Solid `Vector<'t>` is a bit more involved. But the Solid version has a lot more handy functionality and as Jack pointed out, has a number of performance benefits. It also has a lot of useful documentation.

1. You will need to download the visual studio solution from https://github.com/GregRos/Solid
2. Once you have downloaded it you will need to build it as there is no ready to use pre-built dll.
3. If you're like me, you may run into a number of missing dependencies that prevent the solution from being built. In my case, they were all related to the nuit testing frameworks (I use a different one). Just work through downloading/adding each of the dependencies until the solutions builds.
4. Once that is done and the solution is built, you will have a shiny new Solid.dll in the Solid/Solid/bin folder. This is where I went wrong. That is the core dll and is only enough for C# usage. If you only include a reference to the Solid.dll you will be able to create a vector<'T> in f#, but funky things will happen from then on.
5. To use this data structure in F# you will need to reference both the `Solid.dll` and the `Solid.FSharp.dll` which is found in `\Solid\SolidFS\obj\Debug\` folder.  You will only need one open statement -> `open Solid`

Here is some code showing usage in a F# script file:

```
#r "Solid.dll"
#r "Solid.FSharp.dll" // don't forget this reference

open Solid

let ListOfTuples2 = [(1,true,3.0);(2,false,1.5)] 
let SolidVector = ListOfTuples2 |> Vector.ofSeq

printfn "%A" SolidVector.Last
printfn "%A" SolidVector.First
printfn "%A" (SolidVector.[0])
printfn "%A" (SolidVector.[1])
printfn "Count %A" SolidVector.Count

let test2 = vector { for i in {0 .. 100} -> i }
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the good docs! You could also do this in FSharpx, (similar in Solid): printfn "Item(0) %A" vector.[0]; printfn "Item(0) %A" (Vector.nth 0 vector)

Comment: Note that F# has syntactic sugar for `x.Item(i)` which can be written `x.[i]`.

Comment: Thanks Jack, Jon for pointing that out. I have edited the code to be more succinct

Answer (score 5):

Suppose your `dataObj` contains a unique ID field, then any set data structure would be fine for your job. The immutable data structures are primarily used for functional style code or persistency. If you don't need these two, you can use `HashSet<T>` or `SortedSet<T>` in the .Net collection library.

Some stream specific optimization may be useful, e.g., keeping a fixed-size `Queue<T>`for the most recent data objects in the stream and store older objects in the more heavy weight set. I would suggest a benchmarking before switching to such hybrid data structure solutions.

**Edit:**

After reading your requirements more carefully, I found that what you want is a queue with user-accessible indexing or backward enumerator. Under this data structure, your feature extraction operations (e.g. average/sum, etc) cost O(n). If you want to do some of the operations in O(log n), you can use more advanced data structures, e.g. interval trees or skip lists. However, you will have to implement these data structures yourself as you need to store meta information in the tree nodes which are behind collection API.

Comment: Thanks for this. In our current production environment our event data structure has time stamp with microsecond fidelity and we force uniqueness as the moment of event reception ensuring that no two  timestamp are the same. So we could use this as uniqueID. It would also allow time-based lookups. Looking into Queue<T> right now

Comment: @AndreP., Queue<T> does not allow explicit indexing or backward enumeration. So you have to use another implementation or implement it yourself. A queue is very simple to implement, btw.

Answer (score 5):

> This event is placed in a data structure. This is the data structure that we are trying to determine. Should it be a Set, a Queue, or some other structure?

Difficult to say without more information.

If your data are coming in with timestamps in ascending order (i.e. they are never out of order) then you can just use some kind of queue or extensible array.

If your data can come in out of order and you need them reordered then you want a priority queue or indexed collection instead.

> to upwards of around 800 events per second

Those are extremely tame performance requirements for insertion rate.

> A subset of the elements are either extracted or somehow iterated over for the purpose of feature generation. This would either be the last n rows/elements of the data structure (ie. last 1000 events or 10,000 events) or all the elements in the last x secs/mins (i.e all the events in the last 10 min). Ideally, we want a structure that allows us to do this efficiently. In particular, a data structure that allows for random access of the nth element without iteration through all the others elements is of value.

If you only ever want elements near the beginning why do you want random access? Do you really want random access by index or do you actually want random access by some other key like time?

From what you've said I would suggest using an ordinary F# `Map` keyed on index maintained by a `MailboxProcessor` that can append a new event and retrieve an object that allows all events to be indexed, i.e. wrap the `Map` in an object that provides its own `Item` property and implementation of `IEnumerable<_>`. On my machine that simple solution takes 50 lines of code and can handle around 500,000 events per second.

Comment: Can you post your example? I'd like to see it as I'm not totally sure I follow your suggestion

Comment: @Jon Thanks for that well thought out post. To answer some of your questions: The data can sometimes be out of order. The 800 events/per sec is per instrument. The total load would be much higher but is definitely under the 500,000 events/second you mention. We are not sure yet whether we will only need random access near the beginning but for the moment we like to retain the option to look far back. We want both random access by index and by time.  Thanks for the suggestion regarding `MailboxProcessor`. That has come up a number of times in other similar posts. Will definitely look into it.

Comment: @AndreP. If you want random access by both index and time then I'd implement a custom balanced tree. Another advantage of this is that you can store statistics for sub-trees in the branches themselves. You can also extract ranges in O(log n) and iterate over them in O(n) instead of O(n log n).