# F# What is the syntax for creating and populating an FSharpx.Collections.Vector?

Tags: syntax, f#, f#-3.0

I would like to make use of the `Vector<'T>` data structure mentioned here as an answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17961204/818645

but I can't seem to get the syntax right. For example:

```
open FSharpx.Collections

let tuple1= (1,2.0,"f")
let tuple2= (2,3.0,"f")

let myLstOfTuples = [tuple1;tuple2]  
let myVector = ?? <- how do I do this?
```

How do I create a vector of type `Vector<int * float * string>` and populate it with data?

Comment: I provided instructions and code for using both the FShaprx and Solid version of the `Vector<'T>` as an answer to my own question. Hope this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17974392/818645

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the `ofSeq` method as follows

```
let myvector = myLstOfTuples |> Vector.ofSeq
```

Comment: Thanks. is there anyway to do this without using an intermediate tuple structure? I.e. do I need to create a list of tuples first, or is there a more direct way?

Comment: You could just do `[(1,2.0,"f");(2,3.0,"f")] |> Vector.ofSeq` but you need some collection type to pass to `ofSeq`